# asp.net DropDownList event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with a dropdownlist that doesn't seem to "notice" when the selected index has changed. On the form it looks something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLResponsible" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

On the form there is another dropdownlist and when the selected index changes in that one, this one is reloaded using javascript. This works fine. But when i select an item from this list and press the save button on the form, the selected value just doesn't seem to change.

I tried using AutoPostback = true but that just made both lists reload to their original values.

If anyone understands what's going on, please please please explain in to me.

Comment: You've posted too little code. Show the other dropdown list and the javascript code you wrote to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Page.IsPostBack on Page.OnLoad?
If you miss that it would cause this behavior..

Can you post more code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if IsPostBack check is missing in Pageload event.... please check it or if not then please explain you question more.